# Checking time passed accurately on Windows, even if the system clock is changed

Tags: c#, .net

Ideally I'm looking for a .NET way to do this, but C++, batch file, any way to get this information will be fine for me.

Suppose the following scenario with an app I'll call "TinkleBling", just because it's less boring than calling it "AppOne".

Some facts:

- TinkleBling has a trial period of 3 days, starting the first time they open the app
- This user's machine has no internet connection

The steps:

- User opens TinkleBling for the first time on 1st January, 00:00
- User closes TingleBling on 1st January, 01:00
- ... time passes and it becomes 5th January. TinkleBling trial has expired. Boo.
- User changes clock on his machine to 1st January, 02:00
- User opens up TinkleBling

How can TinkleBling know that actually four days have passed and the trial has expired, especially if we can't check internet clocks or do any external checking online?

Is there any way to check elapsed machine time without relying on the system clock? Is there any other counter going on that can be tapped?

Comment: There is no foolproof way of doing this without an external connection (Even with an external connection it is still nearly impossible).  You can do tricks like keeping track of the last run time and never run before that time, but you have to store that somewhere and smart enough users will be able to circumvent that.

If someone wants to get around your license checks, they will do it (i.e. create a new VM for the software and just keep recreating the VM every time the trial runs out).

Comment: Although this began as part of developing a license system, the curiosity is killing me that there is no way to do this. Of course, people will always find a way to not pay/hack/crack it, but this particular problem seemed so enticing to my developer mind to solve just for solving it's sake :)

Comment: (a simpler and definitely implementable but still hackable alternative would be to allow X hours usage of the app running in the trial period, so I'm not tremendously fussed for bullet proofing, I just really, really want to know if someone has an ingenious solution hidden away somewhere, or if there is a machine counter that is going always regardless of system clock - which would still be circumventable if you take out the motherboard battery, of course!!)

Comment: Actually implementing an Elapsed Runtime counter would be more difficult because it requires storing/writing a running total which is problematic.  The hurdles Koerner describes are part of the game: users willing to reinstall pay *their* price in inconvenience.  One way to get an approximate Date  is in WMI.  It has a last system reboot date and a total running time.  Add them and you get a minimum date (run time does not include sleep time).  If it is way off (less than the crypto license install date) refuse to run.

Comment: Not relying on a *single* check is a very obvious workaround.  Limiting the total number of trial runs is a simple other way.  And recording the date of the previous run so you can trivially see the clock being moved backwards is another way.

Comment: Off the top of my head: Look for files on disk that have date/time stamps in the future (Windows config databases, and so on) - alternatively look for entries in the Windows Event Log that are in the future.

Comment: You could also store the date/time stamp when the user logs off your app (or periodically) within a data file somewhere and then refuse to start up if the computer time is in the past relative to the last stored date/time.

Comment: I see now that Hans also had ideas along the same lines as that last one of mine.